# How to deduct time in php?

Tags: php, time

I wrote this

```
<?php
session_start();

if(!isset($_SESSION['now'])){
$_SESSION['now'] = time();
}

if(time() > ($_SESSION['now'] + 300)){
echo "15 minutes have passed";
} else {
echo "waiting";
}

?>
```

What I want to do is, let the user wait for 15 minutes before he/she can view the page. Is the code correct?

Comment: no, it didnt work.. so i need ur help

Answer (score 2):

Yes the code is correct, you can try it simply by having a smaller time constraint.

```
if(time() => ($_SESSION['now'] + 900)){
```

Just to be extra sure.

Try this to see what your variables are printing out.

```
<?php
session_start();

if(!isset($_SESSION['now'])){
$_SESSION['now'] = time();
}

if(time() > ($_SESSION['now'] + 10)){
    echo date("d.m.Y H:i", time())."<br />";
    echo date("d.m.Y H:i", $_SESSION['now'])."<br />";
    echo "15 minutes have passed";
} else {
    echo date("d.m.Y H:i", time())."<br />";
    echo date("d.m.Y H:i", $_SESSION['now'])."<br />";
    echo "waiting";
}

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

The time() function returns the number of seconds since the Epoch.  15 minutes is equal to 900 seconds, not 300.  Other than that the code is correct.